# PHP - delete text from a txt file

Tags: php, email

I have subscribe feature on my site which consists of a simply form in which the user types their email and round the following PHP:

```
$database = "emails.txt"; 
$file = fopen($database, "a+");
$size = filesize($database);
$email = $_POST['email'];
if($_POST['submit']) fwrite($file, "$email,");
if($_POST['submit']) echo "<p style='color:white; margin-top:25px;'>*Check your inbox*</p>";
?>
```

How can I set up a unsubscribe feature where the user types their email into a form and it is then removed from the .txt file?

Comment: Spammers would love to download that `emails.txt` file ...

Comment: `How can I set up a unsubscribe feature` Well, pretty much the same way you set up the subscribe feature. Which step are you stuck with exactly?

Comment: Do a string replace on the text file, replacing the email address with  `""`. Also I'd like to suggest moving from a text file to a DB, or at least a CSV.

Comment: It is a good idea to put each email on a separate line. This is because it is easier to work with a file on line basis in PHP. Moreover, some text editors hate VERY LONG lines. :)

Comment: So my SQL would be better?

Comment: And it's the actual delete function I don't know how to do, I know how to isolate the email, just can't delete what's it

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it

```
$email = $_GET['email'];

$deletedFormat = "";

//read the entire string
$str=file_get_contents('emails.txt');

//replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
$str=str_replace("$email", "$deletedFormat",$str);

file_put_contents('emails', $str);
```

Comment: `$deletedFormat` is empty :). You would eventually end up with file like this: `some@email.com,,,,,another@email.com,,` because you do not delete any comma.

Comment: You could fix that issue very easily `$email = $_GET['email'].",";`. My example was the logic. I'm sure some case conditioning and trim would be required too. I'm not about to write a complete script :)

Comment: All right. Sorry for nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier with a database such as MySQL.

Your solution relies on 'emails.txt' file and it has several disadavantages:

- you should consider the scenario that two people want to unsubscribe their emails at the same time - you need to use `flock` function.
- If you have many emails then it may take a long time to read all emails, write them to a temp file and then rename the temp file to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You could read it all in to an array and then only write lines back to the file that are not a match.

```
$find = 'joe@bloggs.com';
$emails = file('emails.txt');

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    if ( !strstr($email, $find) ) {
        $result .= $email;
    } 
}

file_put_contents('emails.txt', $result);
```

In reality, you should really be using a MySQL database for something like this. It makes searching through and manipulating records trivial, not to mention the security risk you have from someone downloading the text file - it's quite irresponsible to the people who subscribe to your service.

Comment: This approach is usable if the file emails.txt is not large. In the other case the script fails on memory limit.

Comment: Good point. It was more a theoretical answer, the true answer is "don't do that, use an actual database".

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better using newlines instead of commas:

```
if ($_POST['subscribe'])) {
    touch('emails.txt');
    $emails = file('emails.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
            && !in_array($_POST['email'], $emails)) {
        $emails[] = $_POST['email'];
        file_put_contents('emails.txt', explode("\n", $emails));
    }
} elseif ($_POST['unsubscribe']) {
    touch('emails.txt');
    $emails = file('emails.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
            && ($index = array_search($_POST['email'], $emails)) !== false) {
        unset($emails[$index]);
        file_put_contents('emails.txt', explode("\n", $emails));
    }
}
```

Make sure to protect your *emails.txt* file outside site root directory.

You might to want to use a SQLite database for that:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:emails.sqlite');
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscriptions (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)');

if ($_POST['subscribe']) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE subscriptions (email) VALUES (:email)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
} elseif ($_POST['unsubscribe']) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM subscriptions WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

It's not tested, but should work. Make sure to also protect your *emails.sqlite* outside the site root directory.